# How to set up function parameters to get back a 2 dimensional vector filled with values read from a file?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I am struggling to write parameters for a function 'readFile' which parameters are - a file name and a 2D vector to which information is copied from the file. The program doesn't throw ANY errors, but it does return just an empty vector. If i copy the code from 'readFile' function to main() function, it does work, but I want to make a seperate function so I can fill  vectors with information from different files. Also I will need to pass these arguments for different type of functions with similar structure where I read from a file and copy to a 2D vector, so I really have to figure this out.
'PrintVector' function works fine. Could someone help me?

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
 using namespace std;

void printVector(vector< vector <float> > v)
{
 for (size_t i=0; i<v.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j=0; j<v[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            cout << v[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void readFile(char* filename, vector< vector<float> > &rowvector)
{

    ifstream myfile(filename, ios::in);
    string line;
    string field; 
    vector<float> v;                // 1 row 
    float result;                // converted string value is saved in 'result' as a float type
    if(myfile.is_open()){
    while ( getline(myfile,line) )    // get next line in file
    {
        v.clear();
        stringstream ss(line);

        while (getline(ss,field,','))  // comma seperates elements
        {
            istringstream convert(field);
            if ( !(convert >> result) )
                result = 0;
            v.push_back(result);  // add each field to the 1D array


        }

        rowvector.push_back(v);  // add the 1D array to the 2D array
    }

}
myfile.close();
}
int main()
{


   vector< vector<float> > myvector; // new 2D vector
    readFile("test.txt", myvector); 
    printVector(myvector);

return 0;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Put an else statement on `if(myfile.is_open()){` and make sure you actually opened the file.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you so much! You pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, and I guess this could arguably be a matter of opinion, but I think the better approach here is to simply return the vector from your function. A vector can be moved, so even if RVO is not applied, it's very cheap to return a vector.